# Dynamic delete code erases whole table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-delete, dynamic-sql

I have a major problem with my delete statement in my code.

Running *C#*, MySql for Visual Studio and the .NET connector.

It is really basic:

*FYI: Teile = Parts in German*

I have a `List<Teile>` where the item has an ID, a description and a count.
This list is given to my delete function (i know, no parameters):

```csh
public static void Delete(List<TeilShort> Teileliste)
{
    string strSQL = "DELETE FROM Teile WHERE tID ";
    MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
    if (Teileliste.Count > 1)
    {
        strSQL += "IN (";
        foreach (var item in Teileliste)
        {
            strSQL += item.ID + ", ";
        }
        strSQL = strSQL.Substring(0, strSQL.Length - 2) + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        strSQL += "= " + Teileliste[0].ID;
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(strSQL);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (MySqlException) { throw; }
    finally { conn.Close(); }
}
```

The **tID** is the *Primary Key* of my table Teile.

When i comment the whole if-statement and just add `= 14` to `strSQL` then it works perfectly fine and deletes only the entry with the ID 14.

If i have only one item in my *Teileliste* and the code writes itself (the `Debug.WriteLine(strSQL);` outputs the same,
***every entity in my table gets deleted***

Luckily i only had test data in it.

Can anyone tell me where the problem could be?

Greetings
Diego

Comment: Make sure that `Teileliste` doesnt have every ID in it, using some sort of view might filter some/most out.  That loop could be replaced with `string.Join(",", Teileliste)`

Comment: I am sure that `Teileliste` has only one ID, since the `Debug.WriteLine` shows the `=ID` and not an `IN ()`statement.
How do i get the ID's out of the `Teileliste` since there are the items `ID, Description and Partcount` in it?

Comment: Please poste the SQL command you get in your `Debug.Print` as well with just one ID as with more than one.

Comment: @Shnugo
With only one item to delte it's: `DELETE FROM Teile WHERE tID = 18`

With more than one: `DELETE FROM Teile WHERE tID IN (18, 17)`

When i copy this into my PhpMyAdmin it works prefectly fine.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was a `List<string>`: `string.Join(",", Teileliste.Select( s=> s.Id.ToString().ToArray()));`

Comment: Please post also the setup of your test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define your command on top of your routine with

```
string strSQL = "DELETE FROM Teile WHERE tID ";
MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
```

After this you build your command string but you never set this new command into your command object. So your int-ID is interpreted as boolean value. Everything other than 0 is *true*. That's why you delete everything...

Try to move the `new MySqlCommand...` after the command's generation...

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem! Now i feel stupid :D

Comment: @Diego Never mind, there's everywhere a green bush to hide! Happy coding! Grüße aus Wien!